# Display Banner after mysql first result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display banner after first result of MySQL query, after banner it will display the remaining results.

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name FROM database 
                             WHERE id > '".$id."' LIMIT 5");

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $name = $row['name'];
      echo $name;
    }
}
```

### Example Result:

Peter
**Banner Code Here**
Steve
David
Adam

Comment: it seems, here you tried nothing for banner code , it is simple data fetching  code..!! have you tried anything for printing banner ?

Comment: currently not tried. I m Just Asking for how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you not explained your question in well manner so tried on the basis of my understandings try this maybe helpful,

```
$isDispaly_Banner = true;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, name FROM database WHERE id > '".$id."' LIMIT 5");

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

       $name = $row['name'];
        echo $name;
        if($isDispaly_Banner){
               echo "Banner COde Here";
               $isDispaly_Banner = false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: its my pleasure, you can also upvote my answer if its exactly meet your requirements. so other people can easily  go through it.